# Recover a dynamic id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript code that retrieves an id from a CollectionType Symfony:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.well').change(function () {
    var day_n = document.getElementById('command_billet_billet_0_dateBirthday_day').value;
    var month_n =
document.getElementById('command_billet_billet_0_dateBirthday_month').value;
    var year_n =
document.getElementById('command_billet_billet_0_dateBirthday_year').value;
```

Each time a new form is added, this id will become

```js
document.getElementById('command_billet_billet_1_dateBirthday_day').value;
document.getElementById('command_billet_billet_1_dateBirthday_month').value;
document.getElementById('command_billet_billet_1_dateBirthday_year').value;

document.getElementById('command_billet_billet_2_dateBirthday_day').value;
document.getElementById('command_billet_billet_2_dateBirthday_month').value;
document.getElementById('command_billet_billet_2_dateBirthday_year').value;
```

the number changes and the end of id (day, month, year)

Is it possible to integrate javascript code inside getElementById to **get all the numbers and make the distinction of the end of id ?**

Comment: First, if you are using jQuery, why are you using `document.getElementById`? Second, since your ID are in predefined pattern, write a regex and get dynamic number

Comment: Use data() api to add id to each element then you can easily count it, without using number in id attribute

Comment: when you are creating elements give them `class` as well.

Answer (score 0):

`document.querySelectorAll()` could do it.

```js
var ps = document.querySelectorAll('[id^=id]');

console.log(ps);

for(i in ps){
   ps[i].style.color = 'red';
}
```

```html
<p id="id1A">Hello</p>
<p id="id2A">World</p>
<p id="id3A">Hello!</p>
```

Comment: Did you test your "solution" ?

Comment: @Andreas, did you look up the snippet?

Comment: Thank you, it works in this case but I did not explain well, I have 3 id:

('Command_billet_billet_0_dateBirthday_day'). Value
('Command_billet_billet_0_dateBirthday_month'). Value
('Command_billet_billet_0_dateBirthday_year'). Value

There is no more distinction after the _0_, I also have the last word of id that changes it would be necessary to add a treatment for (_day, _month, _year) thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

#### Logic

- Fetch all elements using generic selector
- Loop over them and get ID
- Now use a regex or any other string manipulator to get number.

#### Sample

```js
(function(){
  var digitReg = /\d+/;
  var wells = document.querySelectorAll('.well');
  for(var i = 0; i< wells.length; i++){
    var id = wells[i].getAttribute('id');
    console.log(id.match(digitReg)[0])
  }
})()
```

```html
<div class="well" id="command_billet_billet_1_dateBirthday_day"></div>
<div class="well" id="command_billet_billet_2_dateBirthday_day"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can change your html markup then you can use jQuery data() api

Like this :

```js
$(function() {
  $("#getIds").click(function() {
    var ids = [];
    $(".well").each(function() {
      ids.push($(this).data("id"));
    })
    console.log(ids);
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="well" data-id="1"> div Id 1</div>
<div class="well" data-id="2"> div Id 2</div>
<div class="well" data-id="3">div Id 3</div>
<div class="well" data-id="4"> div Id 4</div>
<div class="well" data-id="5">div Id 5</div>
<div class="well" data-id="6">div Id 6</div>


<button id="getIds" type="button">Get Ids</button>
```

Comment: This can attract downvotes as you have used completely different approach. Please add a caveat if OP is flexible to change is implementation.

Comment: @Rajesh Thanks for suggestion